# Scroll Magic Multiple Scenes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [Scroll Magic](https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic) for the first time and I am in general very new to JavaScript/jQuery. I got it to work but it is very messy and repetitive code.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/y0mrf5kg/) is the fiddle. This is the messy code (I just gave this as an example, in my project there is about 50 scenes after each other in this manner!):

```
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

var tween1 = TweenMax.to('#animation1', 0.7, {
    opacity: 0
  });
var scene1 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    offset: 200,
    reverse: true
})
.setTween(tween1)
.addTo(controller)
.addIndicators();

var tween2 = TweenMax.to('#animation2', 0.7, {
    opacity: 1
  });
var scene2 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    triggerHook: 'onEnter',
    offset: 500,
    reverse: true
})
.setTween(tween2)
.addTo(controller)
.addIndicators();
```

Is there any way I can make this code more DRY?

Comment: [https://jsfiddle.net/axnnmoy9/](https://jsfiddle.net/axnnmoy9/1) my first guess

Comment: I keep getting "setTween is not a function" when I edit the JsFiddle.

Comment: I'm actually getting that error when I simply run the JsFiddle. It looks like `ScreenMagic.Scene` doesn't have a `setTween` method at all. I verified that in the browser with Firefox.

Comment: Thx for your code Greg, im newbie on scrollmagic, i try to copy and paste your code but i don't understood how can triggher the animation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm posting this with an assumption that the JsFiddle is missing something since it throws a "setTween is not a function" error. But given your code...

What you really want is a factory object, which gets provided some config data. Perhaps something in this format:

```
{
    "tween": {
        "duration": 0.7,
        "options": {
            "opacity": 0
        }
    },
    "scene": {
        "options": {
            "triggerHook": "onEnter",
            "offset": 500,
            "reverse": true
        }
    }
}
```

Let's just call this "animation factory" `AnimationFactory`:

```
function AnimationFactory() {
    this.controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
    this.scenes = [];
}

AnimationFactory.prototype = {

    controller: null,

    scenes: null,

    constructor: AnimationFactory,

    createAnimation: function(element, args) {
        element = typeof element === "string"
            ? document.getElementById(element)
            : element;

        var tween = TweenMax.to(element, args.tween.duration, args.tween.options),
            scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene(args.scene.options);

        scene.setTween(tween)
        scene.addTo(this.controller)
        scene.addIndicators();

        this.scenes.push(scene);

        return this;
    }

};
```

Then to use it:

```
var animationFactory = new AnimationFactory();

window.onload = function() {
    animationFactory
        .createAnimation("animation1", {
            tween: {
                duration: 0.7,
                options: {
                    opacity: 1
                }
            },
            scene: {
                options: {
                    offset: 200,
                    reverse: true
                }
            }
        })
        .createAnimation( ... );
};
```

Not you've got a nice clean API to use. But you said there are 50 of them on the page, and I imagine that number could change. Additionally, you have a disconnect between the animations and the elements that require them. Why not marry the two in wedded bliss using HTML5 custom data attributes?

```
function AnimationFactory() {
    this.controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
    this.scenes = [];
}

AnimationFactory.prototype = {

    controller: null,

    scenes: null,

    constructor: AnimationFactory,

    createAnimation: function(element, args) {
        ...
    },

    createAnimations: function(element) {
        var tween = null,
            scene = null,
            elements = element.querySelectorAll("[data-animation]"),
            i = 0,
            args;

        for (i; i < elements.length; i++) {
            args = JSON.parse(elements[i].getAttribute("data-animation"));
            this.createAnimation(elements[i], args);
        }
    }

};
```

And to use this:

```
var animationFactory = new AnimationFactory();

window.onload = function() {
    animationFactory.createAnimations(document.body);
};
```

And a little HTML for good measure:

```
<h1 data-animation='{
    "tween": {
        "duration": 0.7,
        "options": {
            "opacity": 1
        }
    },
    "scene": {
        "options": {
            "offset": 200,
            "reverse": true
        }
    }
}'>Animation 1</h1>

<h1 data-animation='{
    "tween": {
        "duration": 0.7,
        "options": {
            "opacity": 0
        }
    },
    "scene": {
        "options": {
            "triggerHook": "onEnter",
            "offset": 500,
            "reverse": true
        }
    }
}'>Animation 2</h1>
```

This gives you unlimited potential. The configs for creating the animations are embedded right in the markup. If different pages had different animations, no need to keep different JavaScript files around. Every page can be different.

Since the `AnimationFactory` encapsulates all of the animations, you can tweak the work flow behind the scenes if you run into performance problems, like staggering the creation of the `Tween`s so you don't have 50 opacity tweens run all at once on the page (which I image might draw enough electricity from the CPU to power a small Tesla).

If you AJAX in some HTML, then insert it into a DIV after page load, the `AnimationFactory#createAnimations` method can be called, and pass in the HTML element that just had its `innerHTML` replaced and you'll get animations after AJAX, not just on page load.

```
// xhr is an XMLHttpRequest object that just got some HTML from the server
var div = $("#someDiv").html(xhr.responseText);

animationFactory.createAnimations(div[0]);
```

Comment: Wow!! Thank you so much for this detailed answer! You helped me tremendously!!

Comment: Indeed - it's worth breaking the no-"thanks! me too!"-rule to say, well, "thanks! me too!". This deserved more than an upvote.